# RegQueryInfoKey: error 87 - "the parameter is incorrect"

Tags: winapi, vb6, registry

I have the following VB6 code which tries to enumerate registry subkeys. This works on all machines I tried it on, except for one new Windows 7 VM that I'm trying to setup as a dev machine.

This is Windows 7 pro, with all updates made. VB6 with SP6.

The keys that I'm trying to enumerate definitely exist. However, on the new VM I'm getting error 87 - "The parameter is incorrect", when calling RegQueryInfoKey.

```
Private Declare Function RegOpenKeyEx Lib "advapi32" Alias "RegOpenKeyExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpSubKey As String, ByVal ulOptions As Long, ByVal samDesired As Long, phkResult As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RegQueryInfoKey Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegQueryInfoKeyA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpClass As String, lpcbClass As Long, ByVal lpReserved As Long, lpcSubKeys As Long, lpcbMaxSubKeyLen As Long, lpcbMaxClassLen As Long, lpcValues As Long, lpcbMaxValueNameLen As Long, lpcbMaxValueLen As Long, lpcbSecurityDescriptor As Long, lpftLastWriteTime As Any) As Long


Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim lResult As Long
    Dim hKey    As Long
    Dim cJunk As Long
    Dim cNameMax As Long
    Dim ft As Currency

    lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(&H80000001, "Software\Speedocs\[...]", 0, &H1, hKey)
    If (lResult = ERROR_SUCCESS) Then
        MsgBox RegQueryInfoKey(hKey, "", cJunk, 0, cJunk, cJunk, cJunk, cJunk, cNameMax, cJunk, cJunk, ft)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this new Windows 7 VM happen to be a 64-bit OS?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Tried the exact code as above (with only `Const ERROR_SUCCESS = 0` added), both on my main dev machine (Windows 7 SP1 x64, UAC disabled, advapi32.dll x86 v6.1.7601.18247) and a spare VM (Windows 7 SP1 x64, UAC enabled, advapi32.dll x86 v6.1.7600.16385), and in both cases RegQueryInfoKey() always return ERROR_SUCCESS on existing keys.

Comment: _HOWEVER_, if I replace the first `cJunk` (3rd parameter of RegQueryInfoKey()), by `ByVal 0` then I get `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. Documentaton for [RegQueryInfoKey()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724902) says that if lpClass (2nd parameter) is a valid address but lpcClass (3rd parameter) is not or is null, then `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` will be returned. If you don't use lpClass, you could change your declare statement of RegQueryInfoKey() to `[..] "RegQueryInfoKeyA" (ByVal hKey As Long, lpClass As Long, [..]` to be able to pass null for the lpClass parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone who ever comes across this: the problem was that VB6 was used in Compatibility Mode (specifically for Windows XP). I am running VB6 on a Windows 7 machine. I remember reading somewhere that VB6 must be used in compatibility mode, and therefore had set it to Windows XP Compatibility. Once I unchecked Compatibility Mode all together, the problem had been solved.